# Why Jquery validator plugin doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, forms

I am trying to use this jQuery plugin for my webPage but it doesn't seem to work at all.

The console shows no error. The file paths are correct too (otherwise console would have should error 404, right?)

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../jquery-validation-1.11.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script src="../jquery-validation-1.11.1/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$().ready(function(e) {
    $(".contact-us").validate({
    rules:{
        name: {
            required:true,
            minlength:5 
        }

    }
   });
});
```

And Here is the HTML code:

```
    <form class="contact-us" action="../index.html" method="get">
       <li><input class="required cont-field name" type="text" size=" 40" name="name" /></li><br />
       <li><input class="required cont-field email" type="text" size=" 40" name="email"/></li><br />
       <li><input class="required cont-field" type="text" size=" 40" /></li><br />
       <textarea class="cont-field" style="width:400px; height: 200px;"></textarea>

        <br  />
        <input type="submit" value=" submit" />
        </form>
```

When I click on the button, it takes me to the `action` page instead of validation. And console shows nothing at all? What would be the way to debug it?

Comment: Does changing `$().ready` to `$(document).ready` help?

Comment: @jterry No, it doesn't.
Now, I know javascript is client side thing but could this be, by any chance due to server misconfiguration?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're including both the full `jquery.validate.js` and minified version (`jquery.validate.min.js`)?

Comment: No, there is no reason as such. I was trying out different things as it wasn't working. It stil didn't work.

Comment: It's working in a basic [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pvtT/) - so I'm betting there's something else in the rest of the page. Is this all of the code?

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? You can use `FireBug` on Firefox to see if all those JS files are actually loaded. Or in Chrome you could use the `developer tools`...

Edit:

`$().ready` isn't recommended, BTW. Use `$(document).ready`. [Source](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: I am using Firebug itself. No messages at all. No errors, no warnings :(

Comment: But do you see those resources loaded from the network (or wherever)?

Comment: Do you reach the ready() handler? You can use `console.log` to check that the code is reached.

Comment: Why are you referencing the minified and the debug version of query.validate ? A small spike works very well. http://jsfiddle.net/64LyV/